# Perl Overloading Weirdness

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

Long story short: we want to mark strings so that later we can do something with them, even if they get embedded in other strings.

So we figured, hey, let's try overloading.  It is pretty neat.  I can do something like:

```
my $str = str::new('<encode this later>');
my $html = "<html>$str</html>";
print $html; # <html><encode this later></html>
print $html->encode; # <html>&lt;encode this later&gt;</html>
```

It does this by overloading the concatenation operator to make a new object array with the plain string "<html>", the object wrapping "<encode this later>", and the plain string "</html>".  It can nest these arbitrarily.  On encode, it will leave the plain strings, but encode the object strings.  But if you stringify the object, it just spits it all out as plain strings.

This works well, except that in some cases, it stringifies for no apparent reason.  The script below shows the behavior, which I've duplicated in 5.10 through 5.22.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my $str1 = str::new('foo');
my $str2 = str::new('bar');

my $good1 = "$str1 $str2";
my $good2;
$good2 = $good1;
my($good3, $good4);
$good3 = "$str1 a";
$good4 = "a $str1";

my($bad1, $bad2, $bad3);
$bad1 = "a $str1 a";
$bad2 = "$str1 $str2";
$bad3 = "a $str1 a $str2 a";

say Dumper { GOOD => [$good1, $good2, $good3], BAD => [$bad1, $bad2, $bad3] };

$bad1 = ''."a $str1 a";
$bad2 = ''."$str1 $str2";
$bad3 = ''."a $str1 a $str2 a";
say Dumper { BAD_GOOD => [$bad1, $bad2, $bad3] };


package str;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

use overload (
    '""'        => \&stringify,
    '.'         => \&concat,
);

sub new {
    my($value) = @_;
    bless((ref $value ? $value : \$value), __PACKAGE__);
} 

sub stringify {
    my($str) = @_;
    #say Dumper { stringify => \@_ };
    if (reftype($str) eq 'ARRAY') {
        return join '', @$str;
    }
    else {
        $$str;
    }
}

sub concat {
    my($s1, $s2, $inverted) = @_;
    #say Dumper { concat => \@_ };
    return new( $inverted ? [$s2, $s1] : [$s1, $s2] );
}

1;
```

I want all of these to be dumped as objects, not strings.  But the "BAD" examples are all stringified.  All of the "BAD" examples are when I'm assigning a string object I am concatenating at the moment to a variable previously declared.  If I declare at the same time, or concatenate the strings previously, or add in an extra concatenation (beyond the interpolated string concat), then it works fine.

This is nuts.

The result of the script:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'BAD' => [
        'a foo a',
        'foo bar',
        'a foo a bar a'
    ],
    'GOOD' => [
        bless( [
            bless( [
                bless( do{\(my $o = 'foo')}, 'str' ),
                ' '
            ], 'str' ),
            bless( do{\(my $o = 'bar')}, 'str' )
        ], 'str' ),
        $VAR1->{'GOOD'}[0],
        bless( [
            $VAR1->{'GOOD'}[0][0][0],
            ' a'
        ], 'str' )
    ]
};

$VAR1 = {
    'BAD_GOOD' => [
        bless( [
            '',
            bless( [
                bless( [
                    'a ',
                    bless( do{\(my $o = 'foo')}, 'str' )
                ], 'str' ),
                ' a'
            ], 'str' )
        ], 'str' ),
        bless( [
            '',
            bless( [
                bless( [
                    $VAR1->{'BAD_GOOD'}[0][1][0][1],
                    ' '
                ], 'str' ),
                bless( do{\(my $o = 'bar')}, 'str' )
            ], 'str' )
        ], 'str' ),
        bless( [
            '',
            bless( [
                bless( [
                    bless( [
                        bless( [
                            'a ',
                            $VAR1->{'BAD_GOOD'}[0][1][0][1]
                        ], 'str' ),
                        ' a '
                    ], 'str' ),
                    $VAR1->{'BAD_GOOD'}[1][1][1]
                ], 'str' ),
                ' a'
            ], 'str' )
        ], 'str' )
    ]
};
```

The behavior makes no sense to me.  I'd like to understand why it works this way, and I'd like to find a workaround.

Comment: potential work-around: http://p3rl.org/Variable::Magic

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1217269), where I wrote a reply (because I saw it there first).

Comment: @daxim I don't think it helps, since it's on assignment that I lose, and magic is lost on assignment.  Not sure how I could leverage that here.  Basically, I want control over when stringification happens, but it doesn't look like I can do that.

Comment: Tip: `sub new {
    my($value) = @_;
    bless((ref $value ? $value : \$value), __PACKAGE__);
} ` should be `sub new {
    my($class, $value) = @_;
    bless((ref $value ? $value : \$value)), $class);
} ` and `str::new('foo')` should be `str->new('foo')`.

Comment: I recommend that you use the `perlbug` command line tool to ask p5p to explain the outcome of [this cleaned up version of your program](https://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=displaycode;node_id=1217306;part=2;abspart=1). Include the output.

Comment: @ysth, See RT#132793. [Commit 55b62dee2d8dffa7b36b3b613ee4727fbefdb9e3](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/55b62dee2d8dffa7b36b3b613ee4727fbefdb9e3) "merely restores the existing buggy and inconsistent 5.26.0 and earlier behaviour."

Comment: @ikegami thanks, I think that will be helpful in trying to fix the perl bug/inconsistency.  though it doesn't quite match what I'm seeing.

Comment: @ysth, The point is this is a known bug, though there may not be a ticket for it.

Answer (score 2):

Well it ain't a great solution and doesn't answer why perl does this, but I got something... I left a few debugging print statements in there.

For whatever reason perl thinks you want to convert the scalar reference to your object to a scalar string. You can trick it into not doing this by adding a reference to the reference, then dereferencing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

my $str1 = str::new('foo');
my $str2 = str::new('bar');

say 'good1';
my $good1 = "$str1 $str2";
say 'g1 ', reftype($good1);
say Dumper $good1;

say 'bad1';
my $bad1;
say 'b1 ', reftype($bad1);
$bad1 = "$str1 $str2";
say 'b2 ', reftype($bad1);
say Dumper $bad1;

say 'workaround';
my $workaround;
say 'w1 ', reftype($workaround);
$workaround = ${\"$str1 $str2"};
say 'w2 ', reftype($workaround);
say Dumper $workaround;


package str;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

use overload (
    '""'        => \&stringify,
    '.'         => \&concat,
);

sub new {
    my ($value) = @_;
    bless((ref $value ? $value : \$value), __PACKAGE__);
} 

sub stringify {
    my ($str) = @_;

    say "stringify";
    say reftype($str);

    if (reftype($str) eq 'ARRAY') {
        say scalar @$str;
        return join '', @$str;
    }
    else {
        $$str;
    }
}

sub concat {
    my ($s1, $s2, $inverted) = @_;

    say "concat";
    say reftype($s1);
    say reftype($s2);
    say reftype($inverted);

    return new( $inverted ? [$s2, $s1] : [$s1, $s2] );
}

1;
```

$workaround gets you the following

```
$VAR1 = bless( [
                 bless( [
                          bless( do{\(my $o = 'foo')}, 'str' ),
                          ' '
                        ], 'str' ),
                 bless( do{\(my $o = 'bar')}, 'str' )
               ], 'str' );
```